# Let $u(x)=(x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta})^{-1}$ $x,\alpha,\beta>0$. Find $p\geq 1$, $u\in\mathcal L^p(\lambda^1,(0,\infty))$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $u(x)=(x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta})^{-1}$ $x,\alpha,\beta>0$.
>
> For which $p\geq 1$ is true that $u\in\mathcal
>  L^p(\lambda^1,(0,\infty))$?

My attempt 
$$\|u\|_p^p=\int_{(0,\infty)}(x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta})^{-p}\lambda(dx)$$

Then I divided the domain in two, leading to

$$=\int_{(0,1)} \bigg(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}\bigg)^{p}\lambda(dx)+\int_{[1,\infty)} \bigg(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}\bigg)^{p}\lambda(dx) \color{red}{*}$$

It's easy to see that
$$\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}\leq \frac{1}{2\cdot\min\{x^{\alpha},x^{\beta}\}}$$

Now for $x\in(0,1)$

$$\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}\leq \frac{1}{2\cdot\min\{x^{\alpha},x^{\beta}\}}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\cdot x^{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}}}},$$
while for $x\in[1,\infty)$

$$\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}\leq \frac{1}{2\cdot\min\{x^{\alpha},x^{\beta}\}}=\color{green}{\frac{1}{2\cdot x^{\min\{\alpha,\beta\}}}},$$

---

Now I can write that

$$\color{red}{*}\leq \int_{(0,1)} \bigg(\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\cdot x^{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}}}}\bigg)^p\lambda(dx)+\int_{[1,\infty)}\bigg(\color{green}{\frac{1}{2\cdot x^{\min\{\alpha,\beta\}}}}\bigg)^p\lambda(dx)$$

So basically we have to select $p\geq 1$ in such a way that both integrals are finite.

The first term is finite iff 
$$-\max\{\alpha,\beta\}p>-1$$
i.e.
$$p<\frac{1}{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}}$$

And the second term will be finite iff

$$-\min\{\alpha,\beta\}p<-1$$
which implies
$$p>\frac{1}{\min\{\alpha,\beta\}}$$

But then

$$\frac{1}{\min\{\alpha,\beta\}}<\frac{1}{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}}$$

which is a contradiction.

I am sure I've made some mistake in my calculation but I am not able to spot it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I didnt spot your possible mistake (maybe some of the chosen bounds is too weak?) but you can assume that $\alpha \leqslant \beta $, then you can took common factor and the integrand becomes $x^{-p\alpha }(1+x^{\beta -\alpha  })^{-p}$. This simplifies slightly the analysis and you can see that

$$
\int_{(0,\infty )}\frac1{x^{\alpha p}(1+x^{\beta -\alpha } )^p}\,\mathrm d x<\infty \\
\iff \int_{(0,1)}\frac1{x^{\alpha p}}\,\mathrm d x<\infty \quad \text{ and }\quad \int_{[1,\infty )}\frac1{x^{\beta p }}\,\mathrm d x<\infty 
$$
what gives you $p\in(\tfrac{1}{\beta },\tfrac{1}{\alpha })\cap [1,\infty )$.

Comment: I am not able to see how $x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}>x^{\alpha+\beta}$

Comment: Im not saying that $x^\alpha +x^\beta >x^{\alpha +\beta }$. Note that $\frac{x^{\beta-\alpha }}{1+x^{\beta -\alpha }}\in[\tfrac{1}{2},1)$ when $x\geqslant 1$, that is, it is bounded, thus $$\frac1{x^{\alpha p}(1+x^{\beta -\alpha })^p}\cdot \left(\frac{x^{\beta-\alpha }}{x^{\beta-\alpha }}\right)^p\in \left[\frac1{2}\cdot \frac{1}{x^{(\alpha +\beta )p}},\frac{1}{x^{(\alpha +\beta )p}}\right)$$ for $x\geqslant 1$

Comment: sorry, I did a very stupid mistake, it must be $x^{\beta p}$ instead of $x^{(\alpha+\beta)p}$. Change it in my previous comment and you will see what I was trying to write,I already edited my answer to fix this

Comment: Now it's very clear. For sure it solves the exercise, I'll wait a while before accepting it to see if someone can add something else to the discussion. Anyway nice answer (+1)